# Why can I iterate over a slice twice, but not a vector?

Tags: rust

If I try to iterate over a slice twice, [it works fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7b4313e5761bada577e05898d4b2d939):

```
let a = &[1, 2, 3];
for i in a {
    println!("{}", i);
}
for i in a {            // works fine
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

If I try to iterate over a vector twice, [it fails](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8a6a75b612cff35956263b8225a2868b):

```
let a = vec![1, 2, 3];
for i in a {
    println!("{}", i);
}
for i in a {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `a`
 --> src/main.rs:6:14
  |
3 |     for i in a {
  |              - value moved here
...
6 |     for i in a {
  |              ^ value used here after move
  |
  = note: move occurs because `a` has type `std::vec::Vec<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I see that the [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) trait takes `self` by value, so it makes sense to me that the second example fails. Why does the first example succeed?

Comment: Pedantically, in the first case, the type of `a` isn't actually a slice, it's a reference to an array of length 3. However, *deref coercions* allow a reference to an array to act like a slice in most cases.

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks for clarifying. Am I right in thinking that the type of `a` in the first example is `&[i32; 3]`, while a slice would be `&[i32]`? Also, is the deref coercion you mentioned visible in [the list here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html), or is it more magical?

Comment: Yes, those would be the types. I lied a little bit, it is a [bit more magical than a dereference](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29993), it's a *coercion*. The docs will be updated soonish with the fix.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Like you said, `for` works by taking the *thing* you asked it to iterate over, and passing it through [`IntoIterator::into_iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#tymethod.into_iter) to produce the *actual* iterator value.  Also as you said, `into_iter` takes the subject *by value*.

So, when you try to iterate over a `Vector` directly, this means you pass the entire vector, *by value*, into its `IntoIterator` implementation, thus consuming the vector in the process.  Which is why you can't iterate over a vector directly twice: iterating over it the first time consumes it, after which it no longer exists.

However, slices are different: a slice is an immutable, borrowed pointer to its data; immutable, borrowed pointers can be copied freely.  This means that the `IntoIterator` for immutable slices just borrows the data and doesn't consume it (not that it *could*).  Or, to look at it another way, its `IntoIterator` implementation is simply taking a copy of the slice, whereas you can't copy a `Vec`.

It should be noted that you can iterate over a `Vec` *without* consuming it by iterating over a borrow.  If you check the [documentation for `Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html), you'll note that it lists implementations of `IntoIterator` for `Vec<T>`, `&Vec<T>` and `&mut Vec<T>`.

```
let mut a: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3];

for i in &a {           // iterate immutably
    let i: &i32 = i;    // elements are immutable pointers
    println!("{}", i);
}

for i in &mut a {       // iterate mutably
    let i: &mut i32 = i;// elements are mutable pointers
    *i *= 2;
}

for i in a {            // iterate by-value
    let i: i32 = i;     // elements are values
    println!("{}", i);
}

// `a` no longer exists; it was consumed by the previous loop.
```

Comment: This was super helpful, thanks. Can I summarize it this way? 1) If a type derives `Copy`, you can pass it through a "by value" function and still use it afterwards, and 2) in some magical way, slices implement `Copy`.

Comment: @JackO'Connor, that's basically correct, except there is really nothing magical in that slices implement `Copy`. A slice is essentially an immutable reference, and immutable references are naturally `Copy`.

Comment: Is the same result as in your code could be achieved the same by using `iter_mut` and `into_iter`?

Comment: Can you explain, why in the first two examples i needs to be replaced by a borrow from i? I didn't now that and that caused me hours of playing around with &, * and mut at all kind of positions.

Comment: @FordPrefect It's not.  That is demonstrating that `i` in the first loop is a `&i32` (not an `i32`), and is a `&mut i32` in the second.  If the types didn't line up, there would be a type error.  It's probably written that way because you can't directly specify the type of a binding in a `for` loop.