# What does it mean to pass in a vector into a `for` loop versus a reference to a vector?

Tags: for-loop, rust

I'm confused by how Rust `for` loops work. Consider the following:

```
#![feature(core_intrinsics)]

fn print_type_of<T>(_: T) {
    println!("{}", unsafe { std::intrinsics::type_name::<T>() });
}

fn main() {
    let nums = vec![1, 2, 3];
    for num in &nums { print_type_of(num); }
    for num in  nums { print_type_of(num); }
}
```

It outputs the following:

```
&i32
&i32
&i32
i32
i32
i32
```

What does it mean to pass in a vector into `for` versus a reference to a vector? Why, when you pass in a reference, do you get a reference to the items and when you pass in an actual vector, you get the actual items?

Comment: FWIW, there's [other ways of figuring out the type of a value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21747136/155423) that don't require the nightly compiler.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The argument to a `for` loop must implement [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html). If you check out the [docs for `Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html), you will see these two [implementations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#implementations) of `IntoIterator`:

```
impl<T> IntoIterator for Vec<T> {
    type Item = T;
    type IntoIter = IntoIter<T>
}

impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a Vec<T> {
    type Item = &'a T;
    type IntoIter = Iter<'a, T>
}
```

You get references for `&vec` and values for `vec` because that's how the iterators are defined.

Sometimes, you'll see these as the more explicit forms: [`iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter) or [`into_iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_iter). The same logic applies; see [What is the difference between iter and into_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34733811/155423)

There's another form that you will encounter: `&mut vec` and [`iter_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter_mut). These return *mutable references* to the elements in the vector.

---

As to why the differences at all...

Using a reference to the vector allows you to access the vector after the loop is done. This compiles:

```
let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
for i in &v {}
for i in &v {}
```

This does not:

```
let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
for i in v {}
for i in v {}
```

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `v`
 --> src/main.rs:4:14
  |
3 |     for i in v {}
  |              - value moved here
4 |     for i in v {}
  |              ^ value used here after move
  |
  = note: move occurs because `v` has type `std::vec::Vec<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Ownership-wise, you can't get a value from a reference unless you clone the value (assuming the type can even be cloned!). This means `&vec` is unable to yield values that aren't references.

The implementer of `Vec`'s iterator *could* have chosen to only yield references, but transferring ownership of the elements to the iterator allows the iterator's consumer to do more things; from a capability perspective it's preferred.

See also:

- [What is the difference between iter and into_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34733811/155423)
- [Why can I iterate over a slice twice, but not a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34572784/155423)

Comment: Probably worth mentioning the third one too: `impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a mut Vec<T>`.

Comment: @Alec not a bad idea, although I sometimes worry about overloading newcomer's minds ;-)