# Is there any difference in these approaches to iterate through a vector?

Tags: rust

Is there any difference in the following approaches to iterate through a vector? Both methods successfully iterate.

```
let vo = vec![30, 50, 70, 80];
```

**Method 1**

```
for uu in vo.iter() {
    println!("uu {}", uu);
}
println!("vo 1 {:?}", vo);
```

**Method 2**

```
for uu in &vo {
    println!("{}", uu);
}
println!("vo 2 {:?}", vo);
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036279/what-does-it-mean-to-pass-in-a-vector-into-a-for-loop-versus-a-reference-to-a

Answer (score 1):

No difference, no.

The second one is `impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a Vec<T>`, and [it just call the first one (`Vec::iter`)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec.rs.html#2026-2033). Since the method is so short, there's roughly 100% chances it's going to get inlined and you'll get the same result (with an intermediate function call if you're compiling without optimisations but that's about it).