# When to use reference while iterating vectors in Rust?

Tags: vector, rust, reference

I'm confused as to when to use references. I have a vector  and I'd like to iterate through the elements inside it.

```
let v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

I can do this using a `for` loop in two ways:

#### Method 1

```
for element in &v {
    println!("{}", element);
}
```

#### Method 2

```
for element in v {
    println!("{}", element);
}
```

In method 1, I use a reference to access the contents of the vector `v`. Both examples compile and give the desired output. Which method to use and why?

Comment: "Method 2" consumes the vector and yields the actual elements, while method 1 only borrows the vector, yielding references to the elements. Which method to use depends on what you want or need with respect to that.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I stick to references as vector types do not have the copy trait?

Comment: @VineetReddy, it depends on what you are doing. References are more common, but sometimes you have e.g. `Box`es with some large structures and want to move them somewhere else to avoid reallocating and then you will use values.

Comment: @VineetReddy You shouldn't limit yourself like that, basically first one lets you borrow the elements of  the `Vec`, second one lets you have the ownership of the elements by destructing the `Vec`. The rest depends on the answer of this question: Do i need an ownership or do i need to borrow?  For more information you may want to check difference between `Vec::iter()` vs `Vec::into_iter()`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62410265/is-there-any-difference-in-these-approaches-to-iterate-through-a-vector and the duplicates linked there.

Answer (score -1):

The below piece of code consumes `v`. Although both methods in your code do the same thing, however after method 2, you won't be able to access `v`. [See here Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dbdefd100e433922796b04d78098cae8)

```
for element in v {
    println!("{}", element);
}
```

Now, most of the times, unless you want to consume the vector, we use references instead of values. If you are given a `slice` or vector reference like say input to an function, you can only use method 1.

```
fn do_something(v: &[i32]) {
    // body of the function
}
```

> argument type could also be `&Vec[i32]`. However, this approach has drawbacks.

Comment: Bad example. [You should not have `&Vec<T>` parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-o).

Comment: IMO, the user can use the slice but I guess that doesn't convey the point. Ok let me add update it.

Comment: So the idea is that, unless I would like values to be consumed, I stick to references as vector types do not have the copy trait?

Comment: Vectors can only be cloned because implicit copy like what c++ does is expensive by default.

Comment: If this is the case, then how come, access the vector through an index -- say v[0] does not move the value?

Comment: Compiler will prevent it. so, you may need to write it as &v[0] instead v[0].