# How to implement IntoIterator for Tree<T>?

Tags: rust, iterator, lifetime

I try to implement IntoIterator for Tree, then I can use " for in Tree ", otherwise I have to write for in TreeIter{...},  but the lifetime error:

```
use std::iter::IntoIterator;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Tree<T> {
    data: T,
}

struct TreeIter<'a, T> {
    tree: &'a Tree<T>,
    count: i32,
}

impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for Tree<T> {
    type Item = &'a Tree<T>;
    type IntoIter = TreeIter<'a, T>;

    fn into_iter(&'a self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        TreeIter { tree: &self, count: 0 }
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for TreeIter<'a, T>
{
    type Item = &'a T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.count += 1;
        if self.count > 5 {
            return None;
        } else {
            return Some(&self.tree.data);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let tree = Tree { data: "abc" };

    for v in tree {
        println!("{:?}", v);
    }

    /*
    let treeiter = TreeIter{tree: &tree, count: 0};
    for (i, &v) in treeiter.enumerate() {
        println!("{}: {}", i, v);
    }
    */
}
```

got error: error[E0207]: the lifetime parameter `'a` is not constrained by the impl trait

```
error[E0207]: the lifetime parameter `'a` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> test-iter/src/main.rs:13:6
   |
13 | impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for Tree<T> {
   |      ^^ unconstrained lifetime parameter
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your `TreeIter` structure and everything else, you don't want to *consume* the `Tree` on iteration, you just want it to *reference* the elements. So you want

```
impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a Tree<T> {
                          // ^^^^^^^^^^^ implement for references to Trees
    type Item = &'a T;
             // ^^^^^ this needs to match Iterator::Item for TreeIter
    type IntoIter = TreeIter<'a, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
              // ^^^^ self is a &'a Tree<T>
        TreeIter { tree: self, count: 0 }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in a for loop like so:

```
let tree = Tree { data: "abc" };
for v in &tree {
      // ^ only iterate via reference
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

See it on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=86f34aad9431429bbda3feb84b427a5c). See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036279) for the difference between `for _ in x` vs `for _ in &x`.

Comment: Another answer to this post suggests a consuming iterator. A fully featured collection will typically have *both*; see [IntoIterator implementations for Vec](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-IntoIterator), there's one for `Vec<T>`, one for `&Vec<T>`, as well as one for `&mut Vec<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

`into_iter()` is meant to wholesale take ownership of the collection. The collection is *moved* into the iterator and is consumed by iteration, not borrowed by reference and simply looked at. That behavior is provided by `iter()` and `iter_mut()`. Your code is thus conceptually flawed, and the compiler error reflects that: `into_iter` doesn't take a borrow a collection with whatever lifetime it already has; it takes a collection and ends its lifetime right then and there. There's no `'a` for you to `impl<'a>` over. Implement it with the right idea in mind and it works

```
struct IntoIter<T> { // e.g. same convention as std::vec::IntoIter
    tree: Tree<T>,
    pos: i32,
}
// due to your dummy implementation, we need T: Copy, but a real implementation shouldn't need it
impl<T: Copy> IntoIterator for Tree<T> {
    type Item = T; // why would iterating over a tree give you trees?
    type IntoIter = IntoIter<T>;
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        IntoIter { tree: self, pos: 0 }
    }
}
impl<T: Copy> Iterator for IntoIter<T> {
    type Item = T; // iterating over an IntoIter should give values moved out of the container (in this case we're copying the same value a few times and pretending they were moved)
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.pos < 5 {
            self.pos += 1;
            Some(self.tree.data)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    for i in (Tree { data: 1 }) { println!("{}", i) }
}
```

Note that it is conventional to provide `IntoIterator` for *borrows* of the collection as well. Again, `into_iter()` should be seen as consuming it's argument... but "consuming" a borrow doesn't actually consume what it's referring to. *This* would use your iterator type, but note that this trait implementation is not what we're using in the above `main`.

```
struct Iter<'a, T> {
    tree: &'a Tree<T>,
    pos: i32
}
impl<'a, T> Iterator for Iter<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> { todo!() }
}
impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a Tree<T> {
    type Item = &'a T;
    type IntoIter = Iter<'a, T>;
    fn into_iter(self) -> Iter<'a, T> { todo!() }
}

struct IterMut<'a, T> {
    tree: &'a mut Tree<T>,
    pos: i32
}
impl<'a, T> Iterator for IterMut<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a mut T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> { todo!() }
}
impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a mut Tree<T> {
    type Item = &'a mut T;
    type IntoIter = IterMut<'a, T>;
    fn into_iter(self) -> IterMut<'a, T> { todo!() }
}
```

These would be called if you did

```
fn main() {
    let mut tree = Tree { data: 1 };
    for i in &tree { println!("{}", i) } // IntoIter for borrow
    for i in &mut tree { println!("{}", i) } // IntoIter for mutable borrow
}
```