# Why do I get the error E0277: the size for values of type `[{integer}]` cannot be known at compilation time?

Tags: rust

In the following code I am getting the error:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `[{integer}]` cannot be
known at compilation time at the line `for n in numbers[1..] {`
```

I did some searching around, but found nothing.

```
fn main() {
    let mut numbers = Vec::new();
    numbers.push(1);
    numbers.push(32);
    numbers.push(43);
    numbers.push(42);
    // ... And many more
    println!("{:?}", numbers); // Sanity

    let mut sum = 0;

    // Problem code area
    for n in numbers[1..] {
        sum = sum + n;
    } 
    // Problem code area

    println!("{}", sum);
}
```

Also, the problem lines work if I replace them with following (adding `&` and `*` for ownership/borrowing and dereferencing)

```
for n in &numbers[1..] {
    sum = sum + *n;
}
```

Why is the compilation failing in the former way?

Comment: I don't get your question, because you already came up with an solution. What is your concern?

Comment: Also @hellow, the error message you posted is different. It's for the same error code, but not related.  The message posted above is full message.  Did you try running the code?  You can do it here:  https://play.rust-lang.org/

Comment: Please don't accuse anyone on downvoting or voting for close your question. First, I did not downvote it, second it you should look at the full error message! As I posted (it's gone?!) the error message is telling you what to do.

Comment: Sid, when you ask a question and there are some comments, e.g. recommendations or questions regarding the question, then we ask them. When we think, that the question already has been answered, we mark it as an duplicate. It doesn't mean, that it is necessarily a bad question, just that it has been answered. We are happy to help you, when your questions are good, which means they are clear and have a good mcve (when it is about a programming problem). Please read the [info page for rust](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`numbers[1..]` doesn't have a size because it is a bare¹ [slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch04-03-slices.html) of `numbers`. Slices can only be used behind some kind of pointer, e.g. `&[T]`, `Box<[T]>`, or `Arc<[T]>`. The following questions have more information about slices:

- [What is the difference between a slice and an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794235/what-is-the-difference-between-a-slice-and-an-array)
- [How can I fix the error E0277: the trait bound `[usize]: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650259/how-can-i-fix-the-error-e0277-the-trait-bound-usize-stdmarkersized-is)

Because it is unsized, `[T]` cannot implement `IntoIterator`, which is the trait used for iterating over things in `for` loops. (See [Why can I iterate over a slice twice, but not a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572784/why-can-i-iterate-over-a-slice-twice-but-not-a-vector)) [`IntoIterator::into_iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#tymethod.into_iter) has the following prototype:

```
fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter;
```

`Self` cannot be an unsized type because `into_iter` takes `self` by value.

`&numbers[1..]` is a reference (type `&[T]`), which both has a size and implements `IntoIterator`, so it works fine.

The [full compiler output](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=0b55e482967a403c19e70a77c89569cc) also gives an error message about `IntoIterator`, and helpfully suggests using `numbers[1..].iter()` instead. Because [`.iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter) takes `&self`, it can be called on an unsized type, so this is another way to fix the problem.

---

¹In many places, including the official documentation, the unqualified term "slice" is used to refer to the reference type `&[T]`. I call `numbers[1..]` a *bare* slice because it is not a reference; its type is just `[T]`.